# Is it reasonable to make inferences to the population from non-parametric tests?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, nonparametric

I just had it put to me that one can not reasonably make inferences from non-parametric statistics.  This strikes me as absurd as the logical rational supporting counter-factual resampling/rank order alternatives (etc), would seem to be equivalent to the rationale of frequentist approaches.  Where/what is the difference in the logic?  Is it reasonable to make inferences to the population from non-paramteric tests?

Comment: What was the basis of the claim that you could not? Note that the usual permutation-based tests (including most of the rank tests) can apply whether or not you have random sampling from the population, but if you *do* have such random sampling (just as you'd need for most parametric tests) you can make conclusions about the population. You just have to have some care that the conclusions you make are ones that the combination of test and assumptions justify.

Comment: @Glen_b: It boggled me and they wouldn't sit around long enough to discuss it.  So, I figured I'd poke here to see if I was off base.  I concur that the degree to which broader inferences can be made would depend on the characteristics of the sample and ones willingness to make such inferences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether you can generalize does not depend on whether the test is parametric or not but on 1) Whether the assumptions of the test are met and 2) Whether the sample is a random one from the population.